# gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert não é uma função nas permissões da API do Google Drive - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, api, google-api

Eu preciso alterar a permissão de cada arquivo carregado. Mas quando tento adicionar este código,

```
    var body = [
    {
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'writer',
        'emailAddress': 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    }
]
  var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
    'fileId': id,
    'resource': body
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) { });
```

Recebo o erro de gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert  não é uma função.

```
gapi.client.init, gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance(),
```

Estão trabalhando, tanto que consigo deletar/adicionar arquivos, porém para alterar as permissões não está funcionando. Alguém me dizer o pq? Há algo que preciso fazer no código ou na página de desenvolvedores do Google?

Comment: Está usando a API V2?

Comment: Estou usando a v3

Comment: Essa forma que você está fazendo se refere implementação da [V2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert#javascript). Veja a documentação sobre como funciona na [V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create).

Comment: Na documentação do google é dessa maneira que ele indica.....